# Adding multiple allow headers is only adding the last header in http response

Tags: asp.net-core

I am attempting to add multiple Allow Headers to the HttpResponse in aspnetcore v1.1.2. When I run the code below, the headers are added to the IHeaderDictionary on the HttpResponse, however only the last header (in this case "POST") in the collection is actually added to the http response when serialized. Has anyone else experienced this, or am I doing something wrong??

Here is the code I am using.

```
public override async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
{
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Allow", new StringValues(new [] {"GET", "POST"}));

        await next();
}
```

I am doing this within a ResultFilterAttribute.

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue:

```
context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Allow", "GET, POST");
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I have been doing as a workaround, but the fact that the Add method has an overload that takes a StringValues object, I would expect this to work too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, the only place that you may need to change is your response parsing logic. Double check your response - it contains 2 `Allow` headers, not one header with 2 values:

```
Allow: GET
Allow: POST
```

---

Simple example:
Lets say you have next controller action:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    [AddHeader]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Get request using [curl](http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/#downloads):

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/api/values -i
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 22:23:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Allow: GET
Allow: POST

["value1","value2"]
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i only get the one allow header when testing this through fiddler.